# Single user multi login prevention upon browser close

Tags: oracle, jsp, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a table with a field 'loginStatus'. Now everytime a user logs in, the value is set to 1 and after clicking on logout the value is set to 0. Now when a user tries to log in, the value of that field is checked, If it is 0 then the user can log in, if it is 1 then the user cannot login. Now if by any mean the browser is closed, the user cannot login with that userID. Because the value of that field is still 1(he hasn't clicked the logout button so it is not changed). My application is running fine unless the user closes the browser.

I know this issue can be solved differently but I have been asked to do it this way. Now the problem is I am not that much pro in Java EE so multiple help with explanations are exactly what I am looking for.

Also I have a possible solution which is like : creating a database trigger to change the loginStatus value to 0 which will be triggered after, say 15 mins, as the user logs in. Now I also dont know how to create that kind of trigger that will trigger after specific time.

Answer (score 2):

If you've had this requirement forced on you, you can automatically expire accounts without having to run any job.

Instead of a simple "on/off" flag, have a date/timestamp on the table which is set to the current date/time. Every now and then when the user hits the server with a request, you'd update this column to the current time.

If a second session tries to login, that session should check the date/timestamp on the table, and if it's more than 15 minutes ago, the login is allowed; otherwise it is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a database job that runs periodically and expires old sessions.  Depending on the version of Oracle you're using, you can either use the `DBMS_JOB` package or the more sophisticated `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.  `DBMS_JOB` is an older package but for relatively simple and isolated tasks like this, there is less of a learning curve.  For example, if you have a stored procedure `UNLOCK_ACCOUNTS` that, when executed, determines which accounts to unlock and unlocks them, you can use `DBMS_JOB` to have that procedure run every 15 minutes

```
DECLARE
  l_jobno INTEGER;
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   'BEGIN unlock_accounts; END;',
                   sysdate + interval '15' minute,
                   'sysdate + interval ''15'' minute' );
  commit;
END;
```

Of course, you could also use a Java scheduler ([Quartz](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://quartz-scheduler.org/&ei=Sz6HT7nKA8Oz8AHV2sixCA&usg=AFQjCNHPsctgmtehwPa9p4ipUiTUT11M-A) is a popular one) or the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package to do the same thing.  This does require, however, that there is a field somewhere that stores the login timestamp so that the `UNLOCK_ACCOUNTS` procedure can figure out which logins happened more than 15 minutes ago.

Generally, however, this entire architecture is rather suspect.  It's pretty odd that you'd want to have a web-based application (which is inherently stateless) deny logins because the user had opened another browser at some earlier point in time.  It's relatively common to time out sessions if they have been inactive for a while as a security matter, but 15 minutes is generally way too short for that sort of thing-- even bank web sites generally allow you to be idle longer than that.  And this approach doesn't even appear to prevent you from being logged in from multiple browsers/ computers at the same time so long as the logins happened to come more than 15 minutes apart.